# c++, Call dll function with string reference/pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, stdstring, dllexport

I have a solution with two projects, one DLL and one console app. The console app is a client to call and test functions in the DLL.

For the first function `greetings`, I have faced a problem. I should mention that I am totally new to C and C++.

The DLL project (called plugin) looks like this:

plugin.h

```
#include "types.h" // which contains S32 and #include<string>
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
EXPORT S32 WINAPI _3Greetings(string *str);
```

plugin.cpp

```
#include "plugin.h"
S32 __stdcall _3Greetings(string *str)
{
    *str = "Hello From Plugin!";
    return -1;
}
```

All DLL functions should return `-1` on success or `[1-255]` on failure. Also, the project has `plugin.def` to solve name decorating of the `__stdcall` calling convention.

The console app looks like this:

```
typedef U32(*GetGreetings)(string);    
HMODULE DllHandler = ::LoadLibrary(L"plugin.dll");
        if (DllHandler != NULL) {
            string greetingText;
            GetGreetings greetings = reinterpret_cast<GetGreetings>(GetProcAddress(DllHandler2, "_3Greetings"));
            greetings(&greetingText); // THE PROBLEM HERE
            cout << greetings << endl;
        }
```

The problem is if I add `&` to `greetingText`, I get an error:

> E0415     no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::string *" to "std::basic_string, std::allocator>"

And also:

> C2664 'U32 (std::string)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string *' to 'std::string'

If I do not put the `&`, I get a runtime exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x0FA65A72 (plugin.dll) in ConsoleApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCC00.

Comment: Take a look at the type-alias `GetGreetings` in your application, and compare it to the declaration of `_3Greetings` in the DLL. Are they the same?

Comment: And if you want to pass things by reference, *use* references instead of pointers.

Comment: Non-POD types, such as `std::string`, are not interop-safe and should not be passed over the DLL boundary like this at all. Even if the DLL and EXE are compiled with the same version of the same compiler, it is still not safe. So just don't do it. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typedef for GetGreeting is wrong, it misses a *

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that GetProcAdress returns pointer and confused with function param pointer.